# Neo4j Windows Plugin Installation desktop V2.M06

Tags: neo4j, spatial

I have downloaded and installed the latest Window V2 Community M06 build of Neo4j on a windows 7 64 bit machine (I have tried the 32bit and 64 bit installs).

Installation proceeds without and problems and the system runs normally but there is no /plugins directory (on both versions):-

```
\Program Files (x86)\Neo4j Community\
\Program Files (x86)\Neo4j Community\.install4j
\Program Files (x86)\Neo4j Community\bin
```

I am trying to install the Spatial plugin .. so I tried creating the \plugins directory. I extracted the zip file and left the zip file in the directory but the plugins are not found:-

```
C:\Users\WFN44217>curl localhost:7474/db/data/
{
  "extensions" : {
  },
  "node" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node",
  "reference_node" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/0",
  "node_index" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node",
  "relationship_index" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/relationship",
  "extensions_info" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext",
  "relationship_types" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/types",
  "batch" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/batch",
  "cypher" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher",
  "transaction" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction",
  "neo4j_version" : "2.0.0-M06"
}
```

I have tried some other plugins, but these are also not found.

Any idea what might be missing?

Extract from the log files:

```
2013-10-17 11:19:31.881+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: VM Arguments: [-Dexe4j.semaphoreName=Local\c:_program_files_neo4j_community_bin_neo4j-community.exe, -Dexe4j.isInstall4j=true, -Dexe4j.moduleName=C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\bin\neo4j-community.exe, -Dexe4j.processCommFile=C:\Users\WFN44217\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j_p6384.tmp, -Dexe4j.tempDir=, -Dexe4j.unextractedPosition=0, -Djava.library.path=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\apache-maven-3.1.1-bin\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;c:\ikvm-7.2.4630.5\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\WFN44217\AppData\Roaming\npm;c:\program files\neo4j community\jre\bin, -Dexe4j.consoleCodepage=cp0, -Dinstall4j.launcherId=24, -Dinstall4j.swt=false]
2013-10-17 11:19:31.881+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Java classpath:
2013-10-17 11:19:31.883+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [loader.0] file:/C:/Program%20Files/Neo4j%20Community/bin/neo4j-desktop-2.0.0-M06.jar
2013-10-17 11:19:31.884+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [bootstrap] C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\jre\lib\charsets.jar
2013-10-17 11:19:31.884+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath] C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\.install4j\i4jruntime.jar
2013-10-17 11:19:31.884+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [loader.1] file:/C:/Program%20Files/Neo4j%20Community/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar
2013-10-17 11:19:31.884+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [loader.1] file:/C:/Program%20Files/Neo4j%20Community/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar
2013-10-17 11:19:31.884+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [bootstrap] C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\jre\lib\resources.jar
2013-10-17 11:19:31.884+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [bootstrap] C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\jre\lib\jfr.jar
2013-10-17 11:19:31.884+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [bootstrap] C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\jre\lib\jsse.jar
2013-10-17 11:19:31.884+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [classpath] C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\bin\neo4j-desktop-2.0.0-M06.jar
2013-10-17 11:19:31.884+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [loader.1] file:/C:/Program%20Files/Neo4j%20Community/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar
2013-10-17 11:19:31.884+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [bootstrap] C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\jre\classes
2013-10-17 11:19:31.884+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [bootstrap] C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\jre\lib\rt.jar
2013-10-17 11:19:31.884+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [loader.0] file:/C:/Program%20Files/Neo4j%20Community/bin/
2013-10-17 11:19:31.884+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [loader.1] file:/C:/Program%20Files/Neo4j%20Community/jre/lib/ext/sunmscapi.jar
2013-10-17 11:19:31.884+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [loader.1] file:/C:/Program%20Files/Neo4j%20Community/jre/lib/ext/dns_sd.jar
2013-10-17 11:19:31.884+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [loader.1] file:/C:/Program%20Files/Neo4j%20Community/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar
2013-10-17 11:19:31.884+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [loader.1] file:/C:/Program%20Files/Neo4j%20Community/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar
2013-10-17 11:19:31.884+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [loader.1] file:/C:/Program%20Files/Neo4j%20Community/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar
2013-10-17 11:19:31.884+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [loader.1] file:/C:/Program%20Files/Neo4j%20Community/jre/lib/ext/access-bridge-64.jar
2013-10-17 11:19:31.884+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [loader.0] file:/C:/Program%20Files/Neo4j%20Community/.install4j/i4jruntime.jar
2013-10-17 11:19:31.884+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [bootstrap] C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar
2013-10-17 11:19:31.884+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]:  [bootstrap] C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\jre\lib\jce.jar
2013-10-17 11:19:31.884+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: Library path:
2013-10-17 11:19:31.885+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: C:\Windows\System32
2013-10-17 11:19:31.885+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: C:\Windows
2013-10-17 11:19:31.885+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: C:\Windows\System32\wbem
2013-10-17 11:19:31.885+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
2013-10-17 11:19:31.886+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer
2013-10-17 11:19:31.886+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0
2013-10-17 11:19:31.886+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit
2013-10-17 11:19:31.886+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn
2013-10-17 11:19:31.887+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn
2013-10-17 11:19:31.887+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn
2013-10-17 11:19:31.887+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio
2013-10-17 11:19:31.888+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn
2013-10-17 11:19:31.888+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: C:\apache-maven-3.1.1-bin\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin
2013-10-17 11:19:31.888+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin
2013-10-17 11:19:31.888+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd
2013-10-17 11:19:31.889+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin
2013-10-17 11:19:31.889+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: C:\ikvm-7.2.4630.5\bin
2013-10-17 11:19:31.889+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: C:\Program Files\nodejs
2013-10-17 11:19:31.889+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: C:\Users\WFN44217\AppData\Roaming\npm
2013-10-17 11:19:31.890+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\jre\bin
2013-10-17 11:19:31.890+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: System.properties:
2013-10-17 11:19:31.890+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: exe4j.moduleName = C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\bin\neo4j-community.exe
2013-10-17 11:19:31.890+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: exe4j.processCommFile = C:\Users\WFN44217\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j_p6384.tmp
2013-10-17 11:19:31.890+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: exe4j.semaphoreName = Local\c:_program_files_neo4j_community_bin_neo4j-community.exe
2013-10-17 11:19:31.890+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: sun.boot.library.path = c:\program files\neo4j community\jre\bin
2013-10-17 11:19:31.890+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: exe4j.consoleCodepage = cp0
2013-10-17 11:19:31.890+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: path.separator = ;
2013-10-17 11:19:31.890+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: file.encoding.pkg = sun.io
2013-10-17 11:19:31.890+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: user.country = GB
2013-10-17 11:19:31.890+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: user.script = 
2013-10-17 11:19:31.890+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: sun.os.patch.level = Service Pack 1
2013-10-17 11:19:31.891+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: install4j.exeDir = C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\bin\
2013-10-17 11:19:31.891+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: user.dir = C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

The Spatial plugin is not yet ported to support 2.0, we are on it :)

Comment: ok. thanks. I tried this one: http://dist.neo4j.org.s3.amazonaws.com/spatial/neo4j-spatial-0.12-neo4j-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT-server-plugin.zip which was marked up as Neo4j 2.0 on the spatial plugin page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I used the windows installer for neo4j V2 M06, which doesn't seem to work with plugins. I used the neo4j binaries loaded the plugin o.k.

Comment: Can tyou please be more descriptive? Neo4j doesn't provide a binaries for a windows installation.